# Help retrieving product code from HTML using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

A webpage has a product code I need to retrive, and it is in the following HTML section:

```
<table...>
<tr>
 <td>
 <font size="2">Product Code#</font>
 <br>
 <font size="1">2342343</font>
 </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

So I guess the best way to do this would be first to reference the html element with the text value 'Product Code#', and then reference the 2nd font tag in the TD.

Ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised at how many people failed to read the "BeautifulSoup" part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strategy is:

- Find text nodes matching the string "Product Code#"
- For each such node, get the parent `<font>` element and find the parent's next sibling `<font>` element
- Insert the contents of the sibling element into a list

The code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


html = open("products.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

product_codes = [tag.parent.findNextSiblings('font')[0].contents[0]
                 for tag in 
                 soup.findAll(text='Product Code#')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `soup` is your `BeautifulSoup` instance:

```
int(''.join(soup("font", size="1")[0](text=True)))
```

Or, if you need to get multiple product codes:

```
[int(''.join(font(text=True))) for font in soup("font", size="1")]
```

Comment: Fails if there are other 'size="1"' columns.

Comment: @Paul: True, but there isn't, and it could be restricted to the table it's in if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex (or something similar):

`<td>\n\ <font\ size="2">Product\ Code\#</font>\n\ <br>\n\ <font\ size="1">(?<ProductCode>.+?)</font>\n\ </td>`

You could probably remove some of the escapes depending on your RegExp engine... I was being cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. I would use the following XPATH for this task:

```
//TABLE/TR/TD/FONT[@size='1']
```

Or, if the font size attribute is not guaranteed to be there and equal to 1:

```
//FONT[text()='Product Code#']/parent::*/FONT[2]
```